# Angularjs: write json data to file

Tags: angularjs

Simple question, is it possible to write json data (received from API) to a json file in my directory structure. The api returns a json string. Is there any method in angular that supports this or do I need to rely on jquery? Extra information on this topic is welcome.

Comment: It's not possible for Angular (or any other client-side code) to write a file onto specific place at the client machine. While there's Filesystem API, it's basically about giving filesystem aliases to the data stored in the browser's context.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the user's filesystem from javascript, instead you should present the user with a save dialog (it's up to the user where to save the file). AngularJS doesn't support this out of the box, you could however save a file to the default download folder by converting the JSON to a [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string and bind it to an [a href](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,ew0KICAgICJnbG9zc2FyeSI6IHsNCiAgICAgICAgInRpdGxlIjogImV4YW1wbGUgZ2xvc3Nhcnki
IA0KICAgIH0NCn0=">json file</a>
```

For more control to save files to the client, you could use [FileSaver](http://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) which has support for older browsers.